# Does an unstressed 'a + noun' become 'an + noun' in spoken English when the noun starts with an 'h'?

Tags: pronunciation, articles

I am what most of the world considers a "non-native" speaker of English. I, however, consider myself a "native" speaker of English because:

1. I grew up speaking English since birth,
2. English is the language that I am most fluent at,
3. I have never formally studied English, I just picked it up as a child as the first language that I acquired.

Recently, a "non-native" friend of mine asked me whether it is "a helicopter" or , "an helicopter", and I realised that I would personally say "a helicopter" when the stress in the sentence was on the noun helicopter, but when the stress was elsewhere, I would say "an helicopter".

Is this correct in the main standard dialects of English or is this some bad habit I have picked up?

Comment: "an" is for a vowel **sound** at the beginning of the word. This question will be closed because it shows no research on your part and is a basic question anyone can google....sorry.

Comment: We used to say _an hotel_ because it was seen as a French loanword with a silent 'h'. Americans say _an herb_ for the same reason, but _helicopter_ doesn't have a silent 'h'.